# Como verificar se um campo Date é NULL C# ASP.Net

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net

Possuo um webService onde faço uma consulta em uma tabela do meu banco onde tenho uma coluna do tipo **DateTime** e estou querendo fazer uma verificação se este campo DateTime está **preenchido** ou se está **NULL**

Estou fazendo da seguinte forma

```
command.Connection = connection;
command.CommandText = "select  DateDesabled from IdUser where UserName = @userName";
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("userName", user.UserName);
DateTime meuValor = Convert.ToDateTime(command.ExecuteScalar());
Debug.WriteLine("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");
Debug.WriteLine("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"+meuValor);
DateTime CurrentlyDay = DateTime.Today;
if (meuValor.equals(null))
```

Recebo a seguinte mensagem de erro:

> "Objeto não pode ser convertido de DBNull em outros tipos."

Comment: Porque ele não é nullable...? 

`DateTime? meuValor`

Comment: Leandro Angelo Explicando melhor, na minha tabela tem um campo DataBloqueio, onde de início essa data não é preenchida. 
Essa data é atribuída por uma pessoa do suporte..

Então estava querendo fazer uma verificação:

select DataBloqueio from User where UserName = @userName;

com esse select gostaria de verificar essa data se for NULL o usuário não tem nenhum bloqueio caso contrario o usuário está bloqueado.

É possivel fazer essa verificação dessa forma ?

Comment: Se você recebe do banco uma Data que pode ser nula... você deve utilizar o tipo `DateTime?`

Comment: @LeandroAngelo o retorno de `ExecuteScalar()` não é `null`. É `DBNull`.

Comment: Muito bem observado @AugustoVasques

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eu acredito que o erro seja gerado nessa linha:

```
DateTime meuValor = Convert.ToDateTime(command.ExecuteScalar());
```

Segundo a pergunta `command.ExecuteScalar()` pode retornar ou uma data, nesse caso tudo bem, ou um `DBNull`, que é quando o erro ocorre pois `DBNull` não pode ser convertido em data e o método gera o `InvalidCastException` como mencionado na pergunta.

Outro problema com essa linha é que `meuValor` é do tipo `DateTime` que é descendente de `ValueType` que por definição não pode receber `null`.

Outro ponto crítico é a linha:

```
if (meuValor.equals(null)) ...
```

Ela ainda não gera erro mas apartir do momento em que erro anterior for consertado, essa linha irá gerar um `NullReferenceException`.

A solução é simples basta trabalhar o valor obtido com `command.ExecuteScalar()`, adequar o tipo de `meuValor` para `Nullable`, que pode receber nulo, e corrigir a linha que então irá gerar erro, adequando a verificação.

```
command.Connection = connection;
command.CommandText = "select  DateDesabled from IdUser where UserName = @userName";
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("userName", user.UserName);

// Obtem o valor bruto do DB
var rawMeuValor = command.ExecuteScalar();
// Trabalha rawMeuValor comparando com DBNull. Se afirmativo meuValor referenciará null senão referenciará uma data
DateTime? meuValor = DBNull.Value.Equals(rawMeuValor)? null : Convert.ToDateTime(rawMeuValor);

Debug.WriteLine("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");
Debug.WriteLine("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"+meuValor);
DateTime CurrentlyDay = DateTime.Today;

//Não sei a versão do seu compilador então não usei meuValor is null
if (meuValor == null) /* Faça alguma coisa */
```